# I want to generate pdf using DroidText FILENOTFOUND exception ENONT error.please help me in this context

Tags: android

I want to generate a pdf file using DroidText, but when I run the file it is showing an error.

```
package com.example.pdf;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import com.lowagie.text.Document;
import com.lowagie.text.DocumentException;
import com.lowagie.text.Font;
import com.lowagie.text.HeaderFooter;
import com.lowagie.text.Image;
import com.lowagie.text.Paragraph;
import com.lowagie.text.Phrase;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfContentByte;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
//import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Button b;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        b= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                createPDF();
            }
        });
    }

    public void createPDF()
    {
        Document doc = new Document();

        try {
            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/droidText";
            File dir = new File(path);
            if(!dir.exists())
            {
                System.out.println("123");
                dir.mkdirs();
            }
            File pdfFile = new File(path, "sample.pdf");

            Log.d("PDFCreator", "PDF Path: " + "C:/Users/ABHINAV/workspace/PDF/SDCard/droidText");

            //File file = new File(dir, "sample.pdf");
            FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(pdfFile);

            PdfWriter docWriter=PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, fOut);

            //open the document
            doc.open();
            PdfContentByte cb = docWriter.getDirectContent();

            Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph("Hi! I am generating my first PDF using DroidText");
            Font paraFont= new Font(Font.COURIER);
            p1.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);
            p1.setFont(paraFont);

            //add paragraph to document    
            doc.add(p1);

            Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph("This is an example of a simple paragraph");
            Font paraFont2= new Font(Font.COURIER,14.0f,Color.GREEN);
            p2.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);
            p2.setFont(paraFont2);

            doc.add(p2);

            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getBaseContext().getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100 , stream);
            Image myImg = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
            myImg.setAlignment(Image.MIDDLE);

            //add image to document
            doc.add(myImg);

            //set footer
            Phrase footerText = new Phrase("This is an example of a footer");
            HeaderFooter pdfFooter = new HeaderFooter(footerText, false);
            doc.setFooter(pdfFooter);
        }
        catch (DocumentException de) {
            Log.e("PDFCreator", "DocumentException:" + de);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("PDFCreator", "ioException:" + e);
        } 
        finally
        {
            doc.close();
        }
    }      
}
```

Comment: If you add the error to the question, that would be helpful.

Comment: `String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/droidText"` needs a slash on the end or it will look for a file not a directory so `String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/droidText/"`

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add Write to External storage permission in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

after  tag.
like.

```
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
</manifest>
```